# LAURA/LORETA source localization in Matlab

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, neuroimaging

Is there a Matlab toolbox for doing source localization using LAURA or sLORETA within Matlab (not requiring additional software like LORETA-KEY, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The open-source Matlab package called Fieldtrip has a [source analysis function](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/reference/ft_sourceanalysis) in which you can specify the method you want. These include both sLORETA and eLORETA.

In case you did acquire LOERTA-KEY, you also [import sLORETA files](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/getting_started/loreta) into Fieldtrip and continue further analyses.